# Warning window pops up with error message 'Entry Point Not Found' when switching kernels in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When switching kernels in Jupyter Notebook, a warning window pops up with the error message 'Entry Point Not Found' only for my newly created virtual environment. Switching to other virtual environments works normally. I've tried replacing the error file mentioned in the warning window, but it doesn't seem to work. How can I fix this?

[image: screenshot of error message in Chinese, on Windows]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.